# Text isn't justified

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable

I try to write my small books in LaTeX but I can't do it.

The problems:

**1. Text isn't justified.**

Here is my source code.

```
\documentclass[slovak]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=10mm,bottom=15mm,left=10mm,right=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tipa}

\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\setlength{\textwidth}{80mm}
\setlength{\linewidth}{70mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}

\begin{document}
\Large
\input{words_n.txt} % input file
\end{document}
```

Input file is a text file. There are many English and Slovak words (an English word + a pronunciation + a Slovak meaning).

Here is an example:

```
\textbf{hand}        % English
\blacktriangleright  % symbol 
[\textipa{h\ae nd}]  % English pronunciation
\begin{sffamily}  ruka \end{sffamily} % Slovak meaning
```

When I compile the tex file  result looks this:
[image]
I tied to change parametres

```
\setlength{\textwidth}{80mm}
\setlength{\linewidth}{70mm}
```

but result is the same. Can you help me, please?

When I used `multicols` or `longtable` text looks right but I don't want to have two columns and at *longtable* first page is clear, on the second page there is a text but on other pages are nothing, just two pages. 
[image: Result.]

Comment: NO NEED TO SHOUT, add `\sloppy`

Comment: What about adding `\usepackage{microtype}`?

Comment: The hyphenation of the English words is all wrong too.  You could consider loading USEnglish and Slovak with `babel` and then using (for example) `\foreignlanguage{USEnglish}{soup bowls}` to get better English hyphenation (or UKEnglish if you prefer of course).

Comment: You might like to read the learned professor's [work on the subject](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/gregorio/gregorio.pdf).

Comment: Great choice of English words in the second example by the way :-)

Comment: Does the log file mention anything about overfull hboxes?